# How to load data to app widget after device boot

Tags: android, android-widget, data-persistence

I'm trying to read data to my widget after device boot.

My boot receiver is this:

```
    public class onBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public static final String TAG = "BootReceiver";
private Context c;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    boolean dontStop = true;
    while(dontStop)
    {
        try
        {   
            this.c=c;
            if(isExternalStorageMounted())
            {
                dontStop = false;
            }
            else
                for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
                    Log.d(TAG, "###################### EXTERNAL STORAGE NOT MOUNTED ##########################");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
                Log.d(TAG, "###################### EXTERNAL STORAGE NOT MOUNTED ##########################");
        }
    }
    Intent externalStorageReady = new Intent(c, TheWidget.class);
    externalStorageReady.setAction(GlobalVars.WIDGET_INTENT_ACTION_READ_PREFS_AFTER_BOOT);
    c.sendBroadcast(externalStorageReady);

}
private boolean isExternalStorageMounted()
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
    if (Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED.equals(state))
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else if (Environment.MEDIA_SHARED.equals(state))
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else if (Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE.equals(state))
    {
        return false; 
    }
    else if (Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.equals(state))
    {
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

I know I get the `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent (after using it in the widget itself), but I just can't read my saved data.

I read that using `SharedPreferences` is the solution, but what I know is when you boot your device, the `SharedPreferences` is no longer there.

I save the data internally using built-in SQL in the Android SDK.

Please help... :(

Comment: the for loops are for the logcat, i've set it high to see it in the logcat that adb gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External storage may not be ready by the time of a `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. And your loops are pointless.

> but what i know is when you boot your device, the SharedPreferences is no longer there.

Yes, `SharedPreferences` are there at boot time.

> i save the data internally using built-in SQL in the android sdk.

Then it is unclear why you are waiting on external storage, since your data is not on external storage.

Any form of I/O may take too long, though, right at boot time. Have your `BroadcastReceiver` call `startService()` on an `IntentService` that can read your database or `SharedPreferences` in `onHandleIntent()` and update your app widget.

Comment: some clarification needed:
1. the loops are for me to see in the command prompt because everything in the logcat is moving very fast, so don't pay attention to them...

2. do SharedPreferences save data even if i boot my device?

3. i am waiting for external storage because at least then i know that the internal must be mounted....

ill try to use SharedPreferences, if it won't work ill go towards service...

Comment: @Netanel: "do SharedPreferences save data even if i boot my device?" -- yes. " i am waiting for external storage because at least then i know that the internal must be mounted" -- internal storage is mounted before the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast is sent.

Comment: ok, ill try to change my saved data to SharedPreferences, ill let you know if it worked...

Comment: ok, so i changed my data to be saved using SharedPreferences, but now the problem is that i can't set the PendingIntent to the widget.
i try to set the PendingIntent after i get a broadcast from my bootReceiver as mentioned above.

i know these are a lot of questions and it seems like you are programming my app, but i'm new at this so please forgive me if i ask so many questions...

Thanks :)

Comment: @Netanel: I recommend that you ask a new StackOverflow question, with your current code and **specifically what is going wrong**. Saying stuff like "i can't set the PendingIntent to the widget" is not going to get you much help, just as telling a doctor "i don't feel good" is not going to get you much help.